# Identify this connector? (3 pin, similar to JST)

Tags: connector, identification

Can anyone identify this connector?

I removed it from a digital door lock as one of the leads had become uncrimped. Ideally I'd like to buy a replacement with 3 wires/leads crimped on.

I already checked the JST connectors, and I can find some that are similar, but none identical - the single central rib on one side is the feature I can't match. I looked on Digikey, but could not find it (but I'm not very familiar with their system)

Counting pixels, I'd assess the pin pitch to be 2mm. (US penny is 19mm)

[image: connector]

Thank you

Comment: You counted pixels rather than measuring? Regardless, one would advise investing in a 50 cent ruler with inches and mm, rather than a 10 cent decoration, when posting internationally. Or just mm, since that'll still reach upwards of 90% of the world's engineers in good order.

Comment: Haha - yes! At the time of posting I had access to the image, but no access to the connector, so it was the only way. FWIW, millimeters are my preferred unit of measurement and I have a wide array of measuring devices marked in millimeters! I did also note in my question that the coin in question is 19mm wide. Oh, and I'm not American, so you can count me in the 90%  :)

Comment: But the coin being 19mm in diameter means nothing in this picture, because the connector is much smaller and not on top of the coin and the center is the middle of the coin, causing aspect distortion to any size comparison, even when counting pixels.

Comment: That's a rounding error. When I counted pixels it came out as 2.07mm - at least as accurate as if I used a ruler. And as I said previously, I didn't have the connector to hand when I posted, but I did have the image, so this was the only option at the time. It's bizarre to me that you'd make such an issue of this. The fact is that the pixel counting was the only option available, and it worked. Isn't that good enough? Why invest so much effort in chastising me for not using a ruler? I couldn't, I didn't, and it worked out fine anyway. Move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it - a JST PH Series (2.0mm)

http://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/ph-series/8404

Comment: And, as you may already be aware, Digi-key will be happy to crimp contacts onto wires for you.

Comment: I did not know that - thanks. I found a small qty in on ebay shipping from within the US (quick), so went with that.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look, this connector seems very similar.

Please take a look at Digikey p/n: [WM3576-ND](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0873690300/WM3576-ND/2405307)