# What type of 2-pin connector is this?

Tags: connector, identification

Hoping to identify what this 2-pin connector is so that I might 1) order more of them and 2) order a crimping tool that would work with them. I believe the wire in the photo is 26 gauge. Is this enough to go on? Can provide more photos if necessary.

[image: connector]

EDIT:

Here is another photo of the connectors:
[image: connectors]

And here are a couple of the male end:
[image: male end]
[image: male end 2]

EDIT 2:
It occurred to me that I may not actually need to know what type of connector this is, as my real need is to be able to cut these wires to shorten them and then reconnect the existing connector/housing. From the photos, it appears that these housings are an IDC and won't even require crimping? Can anyone sanity check that line of thinking for me? Is it possible I don't need any equipment or parts or knowledge of what this thing is if it is in fact IDC?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/235066/identify-this-connector-3-pin-similar-to-jst). With connector questions, you should always include pin pitch and connector dimensions, pictures like you've supplied are almost impossible to guess from.

Comment: Looks like a 2.54mm pitch JST type connector.   Here are housing of that type, https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-housings/319?k=jst&k=&pkeyword=jst&sv=0&pv88=121326&sf=0&FV=-8%7C319&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25 Pick one and then scroll down to see "For Use With" and "Associated Product" to find a compatible crimp pin.

Comment: Definitely isn't a duplicate! When orienting the pins from left to right, there is no notch on top (or bottom) of this connector, like there is in the duplicate

Comment: I'm not sure of the pin pitch, yet; I've been told that the connector is 3-4mm wide. I will be able to measure myself in a couple of days and should be able to provide pin pitch at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [JST SUR series (.8mm pitch) IDC connector](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/02SUR-32S/455-2176-ND/1300326).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

the connector looks like this : 
https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-AMP/3-644038-2?qs=sGAEpiMZZMs%252BGHln7q6pm5PveGu%252BNdYGW0FVLeX0MgI%3D